# Smoke won't render in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, smoke-simulation

I'm having some trouble with a smoke simulation... I used quick smoke to simulate a candle and it viewed fine in the 3D view, but when I tried to render it, it showed up invisible.

Example images:

Solid view mode viewport:
[image: Viewport]

Rendered view mode viewport:
[image: Rendered viewport]

Rendered via Camera:
[image: Camera render]

Smoke Domain Material node setup:
[image: Node setup]

Please note that I'm using the 'Quick Smoke' option, not manually creating my smoke.

Thanks, Flae.

Comment: Are you rendering on CPU? Currently (as of 7.6) smoke won't render on GPU.

Comment: Oh darnit I was using GPU

Answer (score 3):

I was using the GPU as render device.

I simply needed to change the render device to CPU, after which, it rendered perfectly.

Comment: As of version 2.77, rendering smoke on GPU is supported.

Comment: @cegaton Yep - wasn't out when I answered :D excited now though :3